# How to play a video file in my computer using django with python?

Tags: python, django

I want to play a mp4 file in my computer using django. It is in "C:/Python25/Lib/site-packages/django/bin/script_search/output.mp4" But it doesn't work. The web browser, coolnovo, doesn't display the player screen, instead it just shows the control bar. The thing I can't understand is when I copy the source of the page, changing the url to an abolute one and save it as an html file, the browser renders it well.

The html file is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ keyword }} - script search</title>
</head>
<body>
<video autoplay width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="/videos/output.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>      
</body>
</html>
```

And the urls.py is this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from script_search.search import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', main_views.main_page),
(r'^videos/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': 'C:/Python25/Lib/site-packages/django/bin/script_search/videos'}),
)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I was having this issue for a while, and I solved it, but frankly I'm not even sure why it works.  I put the SRC link in the actual Video tags, and not in a source tag.  Here, like you, is what I started with:

```
    <video width="320" height="240"  controls>
       <source src="{{ HighlightVideo }}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

In this instance, HighlightVideo is just passing a string, which is the full URL.

I was getting nothing, and after inspecting a few websites, I realized that they ALSO listed the url in the video tags themselves, like this:

```
    <video width="320" height="240" src="{{ HighlightVideo }}" controls>
    </video>
```

They also used the Source tag, but I did not need it on my website.